# How to set port for webclient in c#?

Tags: c#, webclient, port

I am trying to download a file using webclient in c#.

the remote port of the file location is 20114. How do I tell webclient to use 20114 port?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

set the url as http://www.website.com:20114/folder/file.ext

Answer (score 3):

My spontaneous guess (without having tried it) would be to simply include it in the url:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile(@"http://host:20114/file.ext", localFilename);
```