# C# downloadFile but different port

Tags: c#, webclient

Need help here, been through this error even I searched the solution still couldnt help me..

I wanted to downloadFile the file with HTTP protocol, but different PORT, which means not using the port 80, but other port such as 5151. The code works fine in C#, compiled without any error. During debuging, it said unable to find path/URL but the path/URL works fine in my browser with the port 5151 (`http://localhost:5151`, work great)..

Any ideas how?

Below is the codes, is there any missing that should I add?

```
client = new WebClient();
            try
            {
                client.DownloadFile(@""+httpAddr + ":5151/factionusers.log", "factionusers.log");
            }
            catch
            {
                client.DownloadFile(@""+httpAddr2 + ":5151/factionusers.log", "factionusers.log");
            }
```

Comment: What's the point of the `@""+` part?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995495/how-to-set-port-for-webclient-in-c.. look this.

Comment: Please change you sample to use hardcoded string - it is very hard to reason what could be wrong by looking at `httpAddr` variable.

Comment: My money's on `httpAddr` having a trailing slash

Answer (score 2):

maybe you add a "/" in your httpAddr variable.

```
static void Main()
    {
        string httpAddr = "http://192.168.56.101";
         var  client = new WebClient();
        try
        {
            client.DownloadFile(@"" + httpAddr + ":5151/readme.txt", "readme.txt");
        }
        catch
        {
            client.DownloadFile(@"" + httpAddr + ":5151/readme.txt", "readme.txt");
        }
    }
```

in my pc. It goes well.

Comment: +1... It is most likely cause. But it would be so much easier if OP used constructor that takes `Uri` :)

Comment: problem solved, the httpAddr was incorrectly initialized to the wrong address (which not exists, misspell the address, lol).. thanks :)

Comment: OK...Congratulations.aha.